# Can adding too much sauce and ingredients to fried rice make it too salty?

Tags: rice, asian-cuisine

I was cooking fried rice. I added sriracha sauce, hoisin sauce, chili garlic sauce, 4 huge sausages, egg, and a bunch of okra. The fried rice was too salty.

Would all of these sauces and ingredients really make my fried rice too salty? What can I do next time to make it less salty.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, absolutely! Sauces can have loads of salt, it all depends on how much you added. You have to look at your ingredients to find the source of the salt in your dish, and then reduce one or more of them:

- Rice: often rice is cooked with salt, if your rice is salty to begin with then adding other salty ingredients could make it too salty. If you plan to add salty ingredients you can reduce the salt in your rice to compensate
- Sriracha: looking at the ingredients on my bottle it has .7 grams salt per 25 grams of sauce. That's almost 3% salt, which may not sound like much but is actually very salty
- Hoisin sauce: again looking in my fridge I see that hoisin sauce has 1.6% salt, which is also very salty
- chili garlic sauce: this varies but they can be pretty salty

Sausages could be heavily salted, but they wouldn't make the rest of the food salty, and okra isn't a factor.

So it sounds like you added a lot of salty sauces to the rice, next time cook the rice with less salt, reduce the amount of these sauces you use, buy reduces salt versions, or use different spices or sauces.